# Inverse of $x^3 + x +1$

Tags: functions, inverse

How to calculate the inverse of function

$y=x^3 + x + 1$

Tried this: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/function-inverse-calculator/inverse%20f%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%3Dx%5E%7B3%7D%2Bx%2B1

But this doesn't show the steps of solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What else have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: [Not very pretty](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+of+x%5E3%2Bx%2B1). I imagine finding the inverse analytically will be...not worth the effort.

Comment: There's Cardano's formula....

Comment: There is no good way to calculate the inverse of this function. Are you sure you're being asked to? In at least one precalculus textbook I've read, you are only being asked to find the inverse *at a particular value*,  which is much much easier. For example, if $f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$, $f^{-1}(3) = 1$ because $f(1) = 3$.

Comment: You would have to solve a cubic equation to find an explicit form of the inverse.  So, that would probably be something ugly: something of a form very roughly like $\sqrt[3]{1 + \sqrt{1 + x^2}} + \sqrt[3]{1 - \sqrt{1 + x^2}}$.

Comment: The link you cite gives $\quad \frac{\sqrt[3]{27x+\sqrt{\left(27x-27\right)^2+108}-27}}{3\sqrt[3]{2}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{\sqrt[3]{27x+\sqrt{\left(27x-27\right)^2+108}-27}}$ as a solution.  So why do you say "but this doesn't show the solution"?  It does.

Comment: @fleablood I meant the steps to solve it.

Comment: @Reese This isn't part of my course, a teacher just randomly challenged us with this question and I wanted to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^3 + x = y-1$
let $x = z - \frac {1}{3z}$

$(z - \frac {1}{3z})^3 + z - \frac {1}{3z} = y-1\\
z^3 - \frac {3z^2}{3z} + \frac {3z}{9z^2} - \frac {1}{27z^3} +  z - \frac {1}{3z} = y-1\\
z^3- \frac {1}{27z^3} = y-1\\
z^6 - (y-1)z^3 - \frac {1}{27} = 0 \\
z^3 = \frac {y-1 \pm \sqrt {(y-1)^2  +\frac {4}{27}}}{2}$

If we say $z^3 = \frac {y-1 + \sqrt {(y-1)^2  +\frac {4}{27}}}{2}$ then $\frac {y-1 - \sqrt {(y-1)^2  +\frac {4}{27}}}{2} = -\frac {1}{27z^3}$

$x = \sqrt[3]{\frac {y-1 + \sqrt {(y-1)^2  +\frac {4}{27}}}{2}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac {y-1 - \sqrt {(y-1)^2  +\frac {4}{27}}}{2}} $